# Getting Info on NON_HID USB Device

Tags: c#, usb

How can I get details on NON-HID USB Devices? Like the serial number, etc in c#?

I have created successfully a sample application to retrieve those information on HID only devices but not on NON-HID USB Devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into LibUSB .Net?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/

I remmber seeing that this was possible, I'll try and dig the article out.

Comment: There is a port of libusb to Windows, which is likely where the OP is working based on the tag C#.

Comment: @RBertieg, hence LibUsb.net? (DotNet being c#?) Did I miss somthing?

Comment: Thank you guys. I will check on that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to retrieve the device descriptors. Assuming a driver has been bound to the device, some of these are already available as they can be seen from Device Manager.